# Looking for simple example of Boost message_queue and serialization usage

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue, boost-serialization, boost-interprocess

Anyone can share small working example of using together boost message_queue and serialization? I want use classes to exchange data between processes but stuck in my research.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work through this.  First try (using the documentation) to make a message queue pass strings back and forth.  Then try using Serialization to turn a struct into a bunch of bytes.  Then it should be obvious how to bring it all together.  If you get stuck, just ask (and post some code showing where you're at).